# Windows console with ANSI colors handling

Tags: windows, colors, console, ansi

Is there any console emulator for Windows that interprets ANSI coloring?

We use rspec and a part of our team use Windows and the special string for coloring are not very useful for them ;).

Comment: Same question on SO: [batch file - How to echo with different colors in the Windows command line - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line/38617204#38617204)

Answer (score 88):

None of the answers on this page mention an important aspect of the new support for **ANSI Terminal Control** which was added to the **Windows 10** console host in build 16257 (and later). Namely, it's *n̲o̲t̲ e̲n̲a̲b̲l̲e̲d̲* by default. Unless the specific software you're using *enables* ANSI processing by calling the [SetConsoleMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) API with the `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING (0x0004)` flag, you won't see colors or get ANSI processing for that application.

> **ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING** 0x0004
> <sub>https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/console/setconsolemode</sub>
>
> When writing with [WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365747) or [WriteConsole](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole), characters are parsed for VT100 and similar control character sequences that control cursor movement, color/font mode, and other operations that can also be performed via the existing Console APIs. For more information, see Console Virtual Terminal Sequences.

I'm guessing the reason the examples shown on this page work is that, apparently the `echo` command (or perhaps the **batch-processing** part of `CMD.EXE` or `conhost`) enables ANSI processing by calling the API just mentioned. But many other tools or executables that write to `stdin` or `stdout` might not do this, in which case you won't see color for those processes.

Fortunately, the global default can be changed from *opt-in* to *opt-out*. The registry key at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\VirtualTerminalLevel` sets the global default behavior for processing ANSI escape sequences. Create a `DWORD` key (if necessary) and set its value to `1` to globally enable (or `0` to disable`) ANSI processing by default.

> ```
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
> "VirtualTerminalLevel"=dword:00000001
> ```

Note that this registry setting controls a *default*, meaning that it only affects console apps which don't explicitly manipulate the console mode by calling `SetConsoleMode(...)`. It follows that, while the registry value may help *enable* ANSI for *console-mode-oblivious* apps, it will have no effect on any *console-mode-savvy* app which (for some reason) may explicitly *disable* ANSI.

[image]

Comment: Note `VirtualTerminalLevel` breaks stuff like `git status` for PowerShell 5.1. Workaround is https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

Comment: In Admin *Powershell*, just use: `Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Console VirtualTerminalLevel -Type DWORD 1`.

Comment: Is it possible to enable ANSI colors via BAT script? without programming and possibly without admin rights?

Comment: @luca.vercelli Yes, you can use the `reg.exe` tool in a batch file to effect the change shown above.

Comment: @GlennSlayden is there... a better way? I would prefer not to be setting any persistent default settings on my users' computers.

Comment: I think the opening sentence on the 3rd paragraph should be reversed to say: `Fortunately, the global default can be changed from opt-out to opt-in.` or to avoid the `opt-out/opt-in` and use your established terminology `Fortunately, the global default can be changed from not enabled to enabled.`

Answer (score 50):

[ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) supports ANSI X3.64 with Xterm 256 color extension. I'm the author of this console emulator.

Ansi sequences are handled for all processes, running in ConEmu tabs.

AFAIK, ConEmu supports more codes, than Ansicon.

[image: ConEmu and ANSI X3.64 / Xterm 256 colors]

Comment: This rocks ! As a gamer I love the quake feature. The console seems to be locked on top of the screen however (even with the option locked on top disabled). Thanks

Comment: how do you run cmd with tabs?

Comment: @Mikey What? Read the answer first.

Comment: Link to the color boxes shown in figure: [here](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/tree/master/src/AnsiDbg).

Answer (score 26):

Starting from Windows 10 TH2 (v1511), `conhost.exe` (and, by extension, `cmd.exe`) support ANSI Escape Sequences, in particular colors:

[image: image from the MSDN page mentioned below]

The [MSDN page about Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx) explains what sequences are supported and how to enable them:

> You can use [GetConsoleMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683167(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SetConsoleMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033(v=vs.85).aspx) flags to configure this behavior. [...]
>
> The behavior of the following sequences is based on the VT100 and derived terminal emulator technologies, most specifically the xterm terminal emulator. More information about terminal sequences can be found at http://vt100.net and at http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html.

Comment: The supported sequences are described at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You can also change the default colors using [Colortool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/08/11/introducing-the-windows-console-colortool/). New Windows 10 installs will get slightly modified colours that are easier to read (especially blue on black), but updates will keep the old, hard-to-read colours.

Answer (score 18):

> Is there any console emulator for Windows that interprets ANSI coloring?

**Windows before 10 - no native support for ANSI colors on the console**

For Windows version below 10, the Windows command console doesn't support output coloring by default. You could install either [Cmder](http://cmder.net/), [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/releases) or [Mintty](https://mintty.github.io/) (used by default in GitBash and Cygwin) to add coloring support to your Windows command console.

**Windows 10 - Command Line Colors**

Starting from Windows 10 the Windows console support ANSI Escape Sequences and some colors by default.

**[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx)**

**Demo**

[image]

**Batch Command**

The [`win10colors.cmd`](https://gist.github.com/mlocati/fdabcaeb8071d5c75a2d51712db24011#file-win10colors-cmd) was written by [Michele Locati](https://github.com/mlocati):

```
@echo off
cls
echo [101;93m STYLES [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[0m [0mReset[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[1m [1mBold[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[4m [4mUnderline[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7m [7mInverse[0m
echo.
echo [101;93m NORMAL FOREGROUND COLORS [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[30m [30mBlack[0m (black)
echo ^<ESC^>[31m [31mRed[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[32m [32mGreen[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[33m [33mYellow[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[34m [34mBlue[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[35m [35mMagenta[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[36m [36mCyan[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[37m [37mWhite[0m
echo.
echo [101;93m NORMAL BACKGROUND COLORS [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[40m [40mBlack[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[41m [41mRed[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[42m [42mGreen[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[43m [43mYellow[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[44m [44mBlue[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[45m [45mMagenta[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[46m [46mCyan[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[47m [47mWhite[0m (white)
echo.
echo [101;93m STRONG FOREGROUND COLORS [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[90m [90mWhite[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[91m [91mRed[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[92m [92mGreen[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[93m [93mYellow[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[94m [94mBlue[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[95m [95mMagenta[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[96m [96mCyan[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[97m [97mWhite[0m
echo.
echo [101;93m STRONG BACKGROUND COLORS [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[100m [100mBlack[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[101m [101mRed[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[102m [102mGreen[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[103m [103mYellow[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[104m [104mBlue[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[105m [105mMagenta[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[106m [106mCyan[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[107m [107mWhite[0m
echo.
echo [101;93m COMBINATIONS [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[31m                     [31mred foreground color[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7m                      [7minverse foreground ^<-^> background[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7;31m                   [7;31minverse red foreground color[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7m and nested ^<ESC^>[31m [7mbefore [31mnested[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[31m and nested ^<ESC^>[7m [31mbefore [7mnested[0m
```

Comment: As of Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.693), the color in Windows 10 has been disabled.

Comment: Why should i believe that? Facts please. a) There is nothing in the changelog: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009938 b) Works for me: http://imgur.com/a/MNPNm

Comment: I'm not sure in what exact Win10 version, but it's mentioned here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19520 On my company laptop -- Ver 1511 (OS Build 10586.753) -- I didn't need it. On my home PC, I had to use ansicon, because the colors weren't on by default.

Comment: They just introduced a flag, which controls colored output and is false by default. See https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/15617610--re-enable-enable-virtual-terminal-processing-by) --- Symfony is using PHP.exe on Windows, where the flag was off, so they had to wait for a patch, which landed here: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2103. Situation resolved. --- For cmd.exe the flag is true always. That's why you have color support on the console.

Comment: would these codes work in a shell script in linux too? or is that done a different way?

Comment: @Mikey http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html

Comment: @ElderGeek that's hardly an answer to his question.  He's wondering (I think) if these escape sequences are the same across environments. I am too, a simple yes or no would work but I don't care enough to diff the two environments :)

Comment: @AdamPlocher IMHO, It's more effective to teach a man to fish than to give him a fish. Since when is a comment an answer anyway?

Comment: @geff_chang Excellent explanation of changes to Windows 10 behavior can be found at https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1173#issuecomment-254250445.

Comment: fyi if you're looking to use colors in a custom prompt, `$e` expands to an escape character. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/prompt

Answer (score 8):

Currently CMD console colors are not enabled by default in Win10, so, to enable it add this to your code:

```cs
#if defined WIN32 || defined _WIN32 || defined WIN64 || defined _WIN64
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD dwMode = 0;
    GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode);
    dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode);

    // References:
    //SetConsoleMode() and ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING?
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772468/setconsolemode-and-enable-virtual-terminal-processing

    // Windows console with ANSI colors handling
    // https://superuser.com/questions/413073/windows-console-with-ansi-colors-handling
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Windows Terminal has support for ANSI escape codes:

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

It is open source, and you can also download builds from here:

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to safely enable Console Virtual Terminal Sequences in your own programs. It's more or less a cut and paste of the code from the Microsoft site with a couple of cursor position control codes on the end.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    if (hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return false;
    }

    HANDLE hIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    if (hIn == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return false;
    }

    DWORD dwOriginalOutMode = 0;
    DWORD dwOriginalInMode = 0;

    if (!GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwOriginalOutMode))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!GetConsoleMode(hIn, &dwOriginalInMode))
    {
        return false;
    }

    DWORD dwRequestedOutModes = ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING | DISABLE_NEWLINE_AUTO_RETURN;
    DWORD dwRequestedInModes = ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT;

    DWORD dwOutMode = dwOriginalOutMode | dwRequestedOutModes;

    if (!SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwOutMode))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    DWORD dwInMode = dwOriginalInMode | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT;

    if (!SetConsoleMode(hIn, dwInMode))
    {
        return -1;
    }


    cout << "blink";


    cout << "\x1B[10;20fHello";


    cout << "\x1B[11;20fWorld" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot #include<iostream> ;-)

Comment: The code mentioned above is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#example-of-enabling-virtual-terminal-processing).

Answer (score 0):

Although you can enable ANSI encoding using the above methods, but it comes with its own limitation. Instead of going through hefty processes, you can use Git Bash, which encodes all of the ANSI colors, and its easy to use.

Comment: gitbash uses msys, which changes the shell, not only the console. that's not what people asked. Just use the new Windows Terminal app from the Windows Store.