# Unable to use ANSI Escape Sequences in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe

I am on Windows 10 and I am unable to display ANSI Escape Sequences coloring.

I've already set `VirtualTerminalLevel` to `1` in registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Console`

Registry Entry:

[image: Registry Entry]

As suggested here: https://superuser.com/a/1300251/1706673

When I open up `cmd.exe`, I type this:

```
> echo ^<ESC^>[7m [7mInverse[0m
<ESC>[7m [7mInverse[0m
```

It just prints it out as a regular text, instead of the ANSI colored text. I've also done the customary rebooting ritual just in case, and nothing changed.

**Caveat**: I don't wish to use third party tools, windows powershell, or windows terminal. I just want to use `cmd.exe` that came with the system. [From this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences), it states that since Windows v1511 (build 10586, from 2015), the system should be able to display ANSI Escape Sequences anyway, so I just want to get this working in my command prompt.

What's wrong with my system?

Answer (score 4):

Those aren't complete escape sequences; they're missing the actual ESC character (byte 0x1B) in front of the `[7m`. In other languages you see it written down as `\e` or `\033` or `\x1B`, but Cmd has no equivalent syntax – so the script you found actually includes the ESC literally. But because it's a "control" character, often it gets lost soon as the script is copied into a website.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> to insert this character at the Cmd prompt (you will see `^[`):

```
C:\> echo test Ctrl[[1mthis is boldCtrl[[m
test this is bold
```

(Note that the formatting codes have a second, normal `[` character – you need to include both.)

One way to include this in your file is to have it there literally, e.g. create an `%ESC%` variable:

```
C:\> echo set "ESC=Ctrl[">>test.bat
```

Comment: Just to note: doesn't work on every keyboard layout. With my German settings, to get `[`, I have to `[AltGr]8`. `[Ctrl][AltGr]8` doesn't work (because `[AltGr]` is the same as `[Ctrl][ALT]`). (Temporarily switching to US keyboard layout does the trick though - if you know where `[` is located on a US keyboard)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `chr(27)` (a.k.a "ESC") to make the ansi sequence complete.
You can obtain it with:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set ESC=%%b
```

(batch file syntax; if you want to do it directly on command line, use a single `%` instead of `%%`)

Then you can use it like:

```
echo ^<ESC^>[7m %ESC%[7mInverse%ESC%[0m
```